# Preventing click handler from firing on jQuery repeatedly but allowing handler execution after a set time from the last handler executed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I did the following: allow the click handler to execute immediately after a click. However, consecutive clicks will disallow the handler from firing at all. 'Consecutive' here is measured from the last time I did `click`. I want to measure the time from the last time the `click` handler is executed instead. I was thinking of something like `startTime` function that can measure the time that has passed since the last `click` handler being executed. Is there such function? If not, what do you suggest?

My code:

```
let tdnTimeoutStatus;
let tdnStatus = true;
$('#toggleDepositNote').click(function() {
    if (tdnStatus) {
        toggleDepositNote();
        tdnStatus = false;
    }

    if (tdnTimeoutStatus)
        clearTimeout(tdnTimeoutStatus);

    tdnTimeoutStatus = setTimeout(function() {
        tdnStatus = true;
    }, 250);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking through, I don't actually need to measure the time from the last time the event handler has fired. Instead, I only needed to `setTimeout` that enables the handler to fire again after a set time after the last handler.

I changed my code above to the following:

```
let allowHandler;
let tdnStatus = true;
$('#toggleDepositNote').click(function() {
    if (tdnStatus) {
        toggleDepositNote();
        tdnStatus = false;

        allowHandler = setTimeout(function() {
            tdnStatus = true;
        }, 300);
    }
}
```

However, I do welcome more elegant solutions.